# Creating an app with a Service functionality

Tags: android, android-service

I was reading this two docs about `Service` in the Android SDK

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

I would like you to explain how the following architecture should be implemented.

I need a Service that every X minutes checks `$something`, updates a db and eventually notify on the status bar the updates.

Then I need an Activity from where I have to read from the same db to show a more complete set of information.

The service basically has to run accordingly to a delay time and even if the Activity is not used.

Is it possible to have this "architecture" in a single apk?

Comment: Take a look at tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: @dierre is db local or remote??

Comment: it's local, a sqlite but I still don't know if I can do it in a single app o I need to let them communicate.

Comment: That's the way to go. Also use ContentProvider for database access, it will handle concurrency for you.

Comment: is `$something` remote or local??

Comment: @dierre as `Mark` said in his answer you can `AlarmManager` however, you can also use push mechanism to notify device whenever `something` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a Service that every X minutes checks $something, updates a db and eventually notify on the status bar the updates.

Use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`. If you need the every-X-minutes logic to occur even if the device is asleep, you will need to use something like my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

> Is it possible to have this "architecture" in a single apk?

Absolutely.